# How can I create an object with type "undefined"?

Tags: javascript, node.js, undefined, typeof

I've read that `document.all` has type "undefined" despite being an object.

```
typeof document.all            // "undefined"
document.all instanceof Object // true
```

How can I create an object with similar properties in my code?

Comment: What exactly do you need to do? And why cannot you use `undefined` for that? `var myObject = undefined`

Comment: I would like to mock `document.all` in Node.js so I can test browser code reliably

Comment: `document.all = undefined` does not work?

Comment: @Thilo I imagine OP is performing some browser capability checks and is trying to produce a convincing `document.all` mock for testing

Comment: Why are you using `document.all`? *This is a legacy, non-standard interface*. Also, if this is a node.js question, please tag it as such.

Comment: @Thilo nope, I get `(undefined instanceof Object) == false`

Comment: I believe the behavior is browser-specific and you can't reproduce it. Even ES6 Proxy objects do not have a trap for `typeof` operator!

Comment: In hosts consistent with [*typeof*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-typeof-operator) in the latest versions of the ECMAScript standard, the only value that can return *undefined* is the undefined value itself.